# Update query failing with error : 1175

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table using the following query

```
update at_product A join
(
SELECT atbillfields.billeditemguid,count(*) AS numberOfPeopleBought
    ,sum(atbillfields.billeditemqty) AS soldquantity
FROM jtbillingtest.at_salesbill atsalesbill 
JOIN jtbillingtest.at_billfields atbillfields
    ON atsalesbill.billbatchguid=atbillfields.billbatchguid
WHERE atsalesbill.billcreationdate BETWEEN '2013-09-09' AND date_add('2013-09-09', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY atbillfields.billeditemguid) B ON B.billeditemguid = A.productguid
SET A.productQuantity = A.productQuantity - B.soldquantity
```

But, getting the following exception:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.

When I gave a `where` clause with the update like `A.productQuantity = 1`, it updated that particular.

Can someone point why I am unable to execute the query and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://justalittlebrain.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/you-are-using-safe-update-mode-and-you-tried-to-update-a-table-without-a-where-that-uses-a-key-column/

If you want to update without a where key you must execute

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

right before your query.

Another option is to rewrite your query o include a key.

Answer (score 6):

This error means you're operating in safe update mode and therefore you have two options:

- you need to provide a where clause that includes an index for the update to be successful or
- You can disable this feature by doing `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

Answer (score 4):

You can try on MysqlWorkbench

Go to Edit --> Preferences

Click "SQL Editor" tab and uncheck "Safe Updates" check box

Query --> Reconnect to Server (logout and then login)

I hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

In `MySQL 5.5`, if you're using `MySQL Workbench` then

- Go to `Edit` --> `Preferences`
- Click `"SQL Queries"` tab and uncheck `"Safe Updates"` check box.
- `Query` **-->** Reconnect to Server (`logout` and then `login`)

This works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I **disable checking the foreign** key using this Mysql command:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```