# Update row Count in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE my_reports AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS count FROM my_reports GROUP BY id) AS B
ON A.id = B.id
SET A.count = B.count;
```

This query is updating the count as 1 each row, because we have unique `id`, I don't want to count the `id`, but I want `user_id`(which is another column). Tried using Right Join but not able to update

```
id           user_id        count
1             33             ? (required 2)
2             33             ?  (required 2)
3             44             ? (required 1)
4             45             ? (required 1)
```

Comment: If you want to group by `user_id` why do you group by `id` then?

Comment: I was trying to use user_id, but it was not successful, while playing i used id, it updated but with count 1. I pasted the query using id here just if in case someone takes reference and helps me so I can easily understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(id int, user_id int, count int);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (1, 33, null), (2, 33, null), (3, 44, null), (4,45, null);
```

So, you want to get the number of records per user_id, which is `SELECT user_id, count(*) AS count FROM myTable GROUP BY user_id`. You can join this to the myTable to update the count:

```
UPDATE myTable A 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, count(*) as count FROM myTable B GROUP BY user_id) B
    ON A.user_id = B.user_id
   SET A.count = B.count;
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/220471/1/0)

Comment: Thanks @Mihe for your help. I was using the same query that you posted as an answer. But MySQL Workbench was responding as 'Query Interrupted'. So I posted here. But when I checked fiddle, the same query is working there. So I logged into the Server using shell and ran the query. Now its working. Can you please help me to unserstand why Workbench is not executing the query...

Comment: I don't know but perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/59564198/19657183 helps.