# MySQL Workbench Error 1175 Even With a "Where" Statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running MySQL Workbench 6.3.8 b1228 CE (64-bit) in "safe update mode". I am trying to run a query **with** a "WHERE" statement, but it still returns "Error 1175"

Here is my query statement:

```
DELETE FROM `my_db`.`table_name` WHERE `email` = 'john@smith.com';
```

(Obviously "my_db" and "table_name" are placeholders.)

Why would Workbench throw Error 1175 for this query when I have the most basic of "WHERE" statements included?

Comment: Did you Google that error? Many hits found, one of which being http://stackoverflow.com/q/11448068/1415724 and another http://stackoverflow.com/q/18767308/1415724  where one of those could be possible duplicates.

Comment: The important part of the error is : "...without a WHERE that uses a KEY column". So i have to ask is the email column a key column?

Comment: Fred, I did Google it, and found many, such as those you posted, that explained how to disable the error by removing SAFE UPDATES mode. What I wanted to know what WHY my query was throwing the error. That is what confused me. Arnolio nailed it. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql by default safe options is enabled which restricts the user from deleting or updating the data in table using inappropriate key.To turn of the safe update go to

`edit->preferences->sql` editor and uncheck the safe update check box at the bottom of the preference window or even you can delete or update referencing the primary key.

For Example: Let us consider we have table called `user_details` with four fields(`name`, `number`, `email` ,`address`) where name is the primary key.
So your delete statement would look like this

```
Delete from user_details where name="xxx";
```

Note: Reconnect to the database after safe update is turned off. Even you can restart the server but reconnect itself works fine.

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is a very simple error. Try delete the row from the user interface. see the attached images.

[image: Select your table and right click in the grid view]

[image: press in apply to see the sql]

[image: here you will see the final query used by mysql]

Answer (score 0):

As [Arnolio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038026/arnolio) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063705/mysql-workbench-error-1175-even-with-a-where-statement/41070239#comment69334736_41063705),

> The important part of the error is : "...without a WHERE that uses a KEY column". So i have to ask is the email column a key column?

I wasn't focused on the KEY portion, and my email column wasn't a KEY, which caused the error. Thanks, Arnolio!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
update
    civicrm_address
set
    geo_code_1 = 99999
and
    id is not null
```

This throws the same error but,

```
update
    civicrm_address
set
    geo_code_1 = 99999
and
    id <> 0
```

is successful

Why doesn't the first one work?

(I wanted to post this as a comment but it doesn't allow the formatting)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue! My SQL statement would not run when I ran this query:

```
DELETE FROM users_delete, WHERE password = 'password';
```

But worked fine when when I ran this query **(see the comma is gone)**:

```
DELETE FROM users_delete WHERE password = 'password' AND id = 1;
```

Safe mode was also off in case you were wondering.