# Regarding SQL delete command

Tags: mysql, sql

I am unable to use delete command in sqlworkbench, every time I am trying to use delete command I am getting an error, which you can see in the image attached with the question.

I am attaching the screenshot of the error. Error is highlighted in green color, the last one:

[image: Error is highlighted in green color, the last one]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update query failing with error : 1175](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767308/update-query-failing-with-error-1175)

Comment: run this code: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

Comment: You can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-
update-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: Thankyou John Woo,it worked! problem z solved now :-)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete using the primary key or from UI otherwise do the following:

MySQL 5.5

1. Goto Edit and then open Preferences
2. Click "SQL Queries" tab and uncheck "Safe Updates" check box.
3. Reopen MySQL