# MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE that includes row KEYs selected from an IN statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a simple update statement that uses a temporary table to select the keys of the rows I want to update:

```
UPDATE table
SET col6 = 1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM temp_table
);
```

This throws `Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode`

However, if I do:

```
UPDATE table
SET col6 = 1
WHERE id = 2;
```

There is no error.

So obviously, I'm using the correct key (id). All id's in the temp_table are distinct (and exist in the target table). There are 9595 rows in the temp table. I tried setting  I am using mysql workbench.

Anyone know what's going on here?

---

**UPDATE:** This works with safe-mode enabled:

```
UPDATE table
SET col6 = 1
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM temp_table
) LIMIT 10000;
```

Still don't understand why, but think it might have something to do with the select limit... Though when I do: `SET sql_select_limit=10000` the original query still fails.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767308/update-query-failing-with-error-1175/18767425)

Comment: Hi @CoderofCode I understand how to disable safe mode, just not sure why the query is being flagged by mySQL (or workbench) as being unsafe as I'm using a key column in the where clause.